# Unsuccessfully attempting to capture XML being sent to a WebService

Tags: c#, .net, xml, web-services, fiddler

So I am having an issue with data passed to a webservice mapping correctly. I am attempting to capture the XML from a .net C# application as it is passed to the webservice. I have tried using Fiddler and system.diagnostics in the web.config but I only get a result in the file created by the system.diagnostics. I am running via localhost, over a VPN (proxy server) to the webservice. Below is the code from the web.config and what it returned. Any assistance getting this returning the data would be awesome.

Code:

```
<system.diagnostics>
    <trace autoflush="true">
    </trace>
    <sharedListeners>
      <add name="console"
      type="System.Diagnostics.ConsoleTraceListener" traceOutputOptions="DateTime" />
      <add name="file"
      type="System.Diagnostics.TextWriterTraceListener" initializeData="testrequest.log"
          traceOutputOptions="DateTime, Callstack" />
    </sharedListeners>
    <sources>
      <source name="LowLevelDesign" switchValue="Verbose">
        <listeners>
          <add name="file" />
        </listeners>
      </source>
      <source name="System.Net.Http" switchValue="Verbose">
        <listeners>
          <add name="file" />
        </listeners>
      </source>
      <source name="System.Net.HttpListener" switchValue="Verbose">
        <listeners>
          <add name="file" />
        </listeners>
      </source>
      <source name="System.Net" switchValue="Verbose">
        <listeners>
          <add name="file" />
        </listeners>
      </source>
      <source name="System.Net.Sockets" switchValue="Verbose">
        <listeners>
          <add name="file" />
        </listeners>
      </source>
    </sources>
  </system.diagnostics>
```

Result from the generated file.

```
System.Net Information: 0 : [5720] Current OS installation type is 'Client'.
    DateTime=2015-06-26T03:22:58.3265794Z
    Callstack=   at System.Environment.GetStackTrace(Exception e, Boolean needFileInfo)
   at System.Environment.get_StackTrace()
   at System.Diagnostics.TraceEventCache.get_Callstack()
   at System.Diagnostics.TraceListener.WriteFooter(TraceEventCache eventCache)
   at System.Diagnostics.TraceListener.TraceEvent(TraceEventCache eventCache, String source, TraceEventType eventType, Int32 id, String message)
   at System.Diagnostics.TraceSource.TraceEvent(TraceEventType eventType, Int32 id, String message)
   at System.Net.Logging.PrintLine(TraceSource traceSource, TraceEventType eventType, Int32 id, String msg)
   at System.Net.Logging.PrintInfo(TraceSource traceSource, String msg)
   at System.Net.ComNetOS..cctor()
   at System.Net.ServicePointManager..cctor()
   at System.Net.ServicePointManager.set_InternalConnectionLimit(Int32 value)
   at System.Net.ServicePointManager.set_DefaultConnectionLimit(Int32 value)
   at System.Web.HttpRuntime.SetAutoConfigLimits(ProcessModelSection pmConfig)
   at System.Web.HttpRuntime.SetThreadPoolLimits()
   at System.Web.HttpRuntime.HostingInit(HostingEnvironmentFlags hostingFlags, PolicyLevel policyLevel, Exception appDomainCreationException)
   at System.Web.HttpRuntime.InitializeHostingFeatures(HostingEnvironmentFlags hostingFlags, PolicyLevel policyLevel, Exception appDomainCreationException)
   at System.Web.Hosting.HostingEnvironment.Initialize(ApplicationManager appManager, IApplicationHost appHost, IConfigMapPathFactory configMapPathFactory, HostingEnvironmentParameters hostingParameters, PolicyLevel policyLevel, Exception appDomainCreationException)
   at System.Web.Hosting.HostingEnvironment.Initialize(ApplicationManager appManager, IApplicationHost appHost, IConfigMapPathFactory configMapPathFactory, HostingEnvironmentParameters hostingParameters, PolicyLevel policyLevel)
```

Comment: Configuring Fiddler for .NET apps: http://docs.telerik.com/fiddler/Configure-Fiddler/Tasks/ConfigureDotNETApp

Comment: Why the down vote? This is a legitimate issue and as I indicated, I have tried using fiddler and it did not return the XML.

Comment: Just to be clear here, did you see *anything* in Fiddler? If not, do you see a request when the VPN is *disconnected*?